# OpenCV - HoughCircles causing program to crash

Tags: c++, opencv, crash, visual-studio-2012, geometry

I want to detect circles in an image using OpenCV and C++.  I COULD do that by referring to the [official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) and adjusting the parameters of the piece of code written by the OpenCV Team.

So, the code I'm working with is as follows: (parameters already adjusted)

```
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace cv;

    int main(int, char** argv)
    {
       Mat src, src_gray;

       /// Read the image
       src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

       if( !src.data )
         { return -1; }

       /// Convert it to gray
        cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

       /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
        GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

        vector<Vec3f> circles;

       /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
        HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 6.0, 5, 110, 70, 3, 20 );

       /// Draw the circles detected
        for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
        {
             Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][2]));
             int radius = cvRound(circles[i][3]);
             // circle center
             circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
             // circle outline
             circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
        }

       /// Show your results
        namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );

        waitKey(0);

        src.release();
        src_gray.release();

        return 0;
    }
```

And the image whose circles I want to detect is the following: [Test image](http://imageshack.us/a/img534/4333/testli.jpg)

These are actually the contour of two blobs that I obtained using cvBlobsLib and redrew as a new image.

That algorithm is able to identify the centers of each circle, but, when I hit any key to close the program, it crashes... :( And I have to forcefully close it.

I need to adapt that algorithm to run in a camera, so I cannot proceed with the implementation while it crashes like that.

So, does anyone know what could be causing this problem?
I'm doing the development on Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV version 2.4.2.

If someone could give me a suggestion of what it could be or maybe try running the algorithm, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started feeling suspicious about the environment, so I got a friend who had OpenCV all set up to try out my code and he could run it with no problem...

So I reinstalled everything, but this time I chose Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and OpenCV 2.4.3, and it worked correctly.

If someone is having the same problem, I recommend downgrading to VS2010. Also, [this video installation guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8) was really helpful when I was setting the environment!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have four advices for you.

**First:** To see whether a `Mat` is empty or not, you use

```
if( src.empty() ) // instead of !src.data.
```

The chances are src.data has random (stale) value for an empty `Mat`.

**Second:** correct the indices like this:

```
Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
```

(actually you don't need cvRound, but whatever).

**Third:** It is worth to check whether `imread` understood that you want to load the image in color mode, by checking its number of channels:

```
src.channels()==3
//or
src.type()==CV_8UC3; // that is what you are counting for, really.
```

Otherwise a line like CV_BGR2GRAY on a gray image could cause weird behaviour.

**Fourth:** you don't need to release Mat's. That's the reason they created Mat class in the first place, so that they automatically take care of releasing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Like I said, I'm a newbie at OpenCV, sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obvious except that you are overrunning the `Vec3f` bounds:

```
         Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][2]));
         int radius = cvRound(circles[i][3]);
```

Instead of index 2 and 3, I think you meant 1 and 2.

That wouldn't necessarily be causing the crash (by corrupting the stack or heap), but then again it is undefined behaviour...

The other thing I suggest is removing the two lines that follow the `waitKey` call:

```
    src.release();
    src_gray.release();
```

These are handled automatically by the destructor in the object, so I don't see why you need to do it manually.  That might not change a thing, of course.

From there, if you are still getting crashes you should start omitting sections of your code until you can isolate the one that crashes it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I corrected the indexes that you pointed out and also took out the lines that I put there to release the memory... And nothing changed :(

Then, I tried commenting some sections of the code, and the only line that made my code crash was the call to `HoughCircles`...

One interesting is that it doesn't cause the crash right after it is called -- the crash only occurs at the `return 0;` line... 
After the call to `HoughCircles` I put a `std::cin.get();` and the program actually waited for the input...

Comment: Yeah, this is behaviour you might see when the stack or heap gets corrupted.  Things can often continue to work until your resources are cleaned up.  In this case, returning from `main`.  So it would seem that either `HoughCircles` or `GaussianBlur` or `cvtColor` is doing something bad.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Please ensure that while running your application in release mode, you are using opencv release dll's. Doing this solved my problem.

Reference:
 https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/953